# Fetch all values for a particular key from a Dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a array of dictionary like this.

```
let arr = [["EmpName"   :   "Alex",     "Designation"   :   "Jr. Developer"],
           ["EmpName"   :   "Bob",     "Designation"   :   "Sr. Developer"],
           ["EmpName"   :   "Claire",  "Designation"   :   "Jr. Developer"],
           ["EmpName"   :   "David",   "Designation"   :   "Project Manager"]]
```

Now I want to fetch only the `EmpName` objects from this. How do I do this in swift? I basically want an array which have the following values.

```
["Alex", "Bob", "Claire", "David"]
```

This is what I do now. But I wonder if I could do that in a single like by using `filter` or `map`...

```
var employees = [String]()
    for empRecord in arr {
        employees.append(empRecord["EmpName"]!)
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way is to use `flatMap`:

```
let employees = arr.flatMap { $0["EmpName"] }
```

Result:

> ["Alex", "Bob", "Claire", "David"]

`flatMap` in Swift is like `map` but it also safely unwraps optionals, which is what we need here since Swift dictionaries always return Optionals.

Answer (score 1):

Here's two ways to do it. If you're cool with using NSArray I'm a fan of that solution.

```
let arr = [["EmpName"   :   "Alex",     "Designation"   :   "Jr. Developer"],
    ["EmpName"   :   "Bob",     "Designation"   :   "Sr. Developer"],
    ["EmpName"   :   "Claire",  "Designation"   :   "Jr. Developer"],
    ["EmpName"   :   "David",   "Designation"   :   "Project Manager"]]

let names = arr.map { (dictionary) -> String? in
    return dictionary["EmpName"]
}
// names now contains array of names as String?

// If you want to use NSArray
let newArray = arr as NSArray
let newNames = newArray.valueForKeyPath("EmpName")

// newNames now contains array of names as String
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, It works well, but @Eric's answer seems to be so simple. Up voted ur answer too!!!